# How to add a new colorscheme syntax keyword

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme

I'm trying to create a new custom colorscheme and syntax highlighting. I have copied some examples into ~/.vim/colors/ and ~/.vim/syntax with new names inside for the scheme.

All the basics work fine, so happy with the files.

I am trying to get some custom colour comments working, rather than just a single one, so something similar to

```
# = Normal comment
##1 = Red
##2 = Dark Red
```

In my colorscheme I have (that I can't get working)

```
hi Comment term=bold ctermfg=4 guifg=#406090
hi Comment1 term=bold ctermfg=4 guifg=#a00000
hi Comment2 term=bold ctermfg=4 guifg=#800000
"" I want to reference these
```

In my syntax file I have...

```
HiLink perlComment            Comment
HiLink perlComment1           Conditional
HiLink perlComment2           String


syn match  perlComment          "#.*" contains=perlTodo
syn match  perlComment1         "##1.*" contains=perlTodo
syn match  perlComment2         "##2.*" contains=perlTodo
```

This partly works, in that I can get the unique comment highlighting working, but ONLY if I match it to a String/Conditional/Comment, i.e an already established 'keyword' or colorshceme or something (not sure what the term is here).

So I was thinking I could do something like...

```
HiLink perlComment2 Comment2
```

To match the earlier colorscheme settings (but this doesn't work, I can't seem to reflect changes from the colorscheme file), so I'm likely misunderstanding what's happening.

Is there a way to create a custom term like String/Conditional that would match in the colorscheme ? I think I'm missing a link somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where the problem is with what you've tried so far. Does `HiLink perlComment2 Comment2` not work?

Comment: Hi Rich, no, it feels like it's ignoring anything anything I set in the colorscheme (but it recognises the colorscheme file when I switch to it). But I can't seem to reference that properly, or I'm missing something.

Comment: What's the output of `:verbose hi Comment2`  ?

Comment: Comment2       xxx term=bold ctermfg=4   Last set from ~/.vim/colors/mycolorscheme.vim

Comment: How about `:verbose hi perlComment2`? And `:syntax list perlComment2`

Comment: perlComment2   xxx links to Comment2  Last set from ~/.vim/syntax/perl.vim   and   perlComment2   xxx match /##2.*/  contains=perlTodo links to Comment2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was an idiot thinking that the colorscheme was using guifg, when in my case it was using ctermfg, so when I started changing that in the colorscheme, all worked fine. So I just needed...

```
hi Comment1 term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=205
```

As an example, the rest was fine.

Thanks to Rich for the help in getting there.